# What should I add or what other way is there?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a dictionary:

```py
test1 = {"SN": "SN: abc123\r\nMAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C\r\n01-04-2022 Замена"}
```

I wrote a regular expression in the code:

```py
name_match_3 = re.search(r"(\r\n.+)", test1.get("SN"), flags=re.DOTALL)
dict_miner_regular["Comment"] = (name_match_3.group(1) if name_match_3 else None)
```

As a result, I'm getting:

```py
result_2 = {"Comment": "MAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C\r\n01-04-2022 Замена"}
```

But I also need to remove MAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C. But it's not everywhere.

As a result, it is necessary to remove SN: and MAC:

```py
result_3 = {"Comment": "01-04-2022 Замена"}
```

I understand that something needs to be added here --> `r"(\r\n.+)"`

Comment: `{"Comment": test1["SN"].split('\r\n')[-1] }` without `regex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `SN` and `MAC` are always directed at the start of a string, then use

```
\r\n(.+)$
```

##### Python Example

```py
import re

test = {"SN": "SN: abc123\r\nMAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C\r\n01-04-2022 Замена"}
match = re.search(r"\r\n(.+)$", test.get("SN"))
result = {"Comment": match.group(1) if match else None}  # {'Comment': '01-04-2022 Замена'}
```

##### *Edit*

Otherwise, you can use the following regex

```
(?:^|\r\n)((?:(?!SN|MAC|\r\n).)+)
```

You can add other keys next to `SN` and `MAC` as well.

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kq1m6Q/1)

Comment: but sometimes Mac is not

Comment: it doesn 't work for me , for some reason

Comment: Please check my edit. I've checked with Python3.6 and Python3.9, and it worked for both. What exactly did not work for you?

Comment: the second method has earned) thank you

Answer (score 0):

if it you need element after last `\r\n` then you can do it with `split()` and `[-1]` without `regex`

```
result = {"Comment": test1["SN"].split("\r\n")[-1] }
```

---

Full example

```
test1 = {"SN": "SN: abc123\r\nMAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C\r\n01-04-2022 Замена"}
lines = test1["SN"].split("\r\n")
result = {"Comment": lines[-1] }
print(result)
```

Result:

```
{'Comment': '01-04-2022 Замена'}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you may have more elements with `\r\n` then you may `split()` to lines, and later filter lines which not start with `SN:` nor `MAC:` and later `join()` rest of lines into string again.

I added `\r\nOtherText` to example data

```
test1 = {"SN": "SN: abc123\r\nMAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C\r\n01-04-2022 Замена\r\nOtherText"}
lines = test1["SN"].split("\r\n")
lines = [line for line in lines if not line.startswith(('SN:', 'MAC:'))]
text = "\r\n".join(lines)
result = {"Comment": text }
print(result)
```

Comment: not suitable as there may be a lot of information

Comment: so you should mention it in question. Without regex you can also split to lines and filter lines which start with `SN` and `MAC` - and later join rest to one string again.